# Ubuntu 20.04 slowed down with addition of external monitor

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed in my laptop before. I did a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 (removed 18 and installed 20). I have a dual boot setup(Windows 11).

When connected to an external monitor everything was working smoothly with 18.04. But with 20.04 the external monitor is extremely slow (frame rate drops, response times lags). I did some search and it was suggested to switch to Wayland but it was also mentioned Wayland has its own set of problems. So, how can I solve this problem?

CPU: Intel i7 10th gen 12 cores
GPU: Nvidia RTX2070
Monitor resolution: 4k

xrandr output:

[image: Xrandr output image 1]

[image: Xrandr output image 2]

Comment: Does this issue happen when using a live USB? Regarding Wayland: it is meant to be better than X. And... in a lot of ways, it is better. But it doesn't do everything X can. For example, some apps don't (fully) work on Wayland. That said, I currently use X, and it works just fine with an external monitor. Can you run `xrandr` and [edit] your question to include the output of that?

Comment: @cocomac I have updated the post with the xrandr output

Comment: Did you by accident plug the 2nd monitor to the Intel card? This is a common mistake when using dual monitors. Both monitors should be plugged to the same GPU. Linux is particularly slow if you mix them

Comment: @MatiasNGoldberg No. Both my HDMI and display port are connected to the Nvidia GPU. But I already found the solution to the problem (check below). But, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. I did this after switching to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I had the same problem with 22.04 as well. The problem persisted even after updating all display drivers. But finally, in Nvidia X server settings -> Prime profiles, I changed the GPU from Nvidia On-Demand to Nvidia (Performance mode) and rebooted. Now everything runs smooth as silk.

Comment: In case, you need to do it on command line, use `sudo prime-select nvidia` and then `reboot`. I had the same issue on ubuntu 22.04LTS and GPU RTX 3050